# How we can change "your default project for interoperable access" to another project in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In my google cloud storage->settings->interoperability, i see **MyprojectName is your default project for interoperable access**, that means **MyProjectName** is my default project. But i want to change that to another project. How can i do that? any solution appreciated.

please have a look into below picture :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do the same and all you need to do is to change project to the [other-project] you want to specify as default project and then in the same page, (Storage>Settings>Interoperability), you will see that there is a choice about "Make [other-project] my default project".

Comment: Yeah, if we are in another project(that needs to be changed) then "Make present project my default project" is coming, but yesterday i been in the existing project only that's y its not shown.